# Is it possible to convert a byte array to a 8-bit signed integer array in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, type-conversion, signed

I am trying to convert a Hex string to an 8-bit signed integer array in Powershell.

I am using the following function to convert a Hex string, such as A591BF86E5D7D9837EE7ACC569C4B59B, to a byte array which I then need to convert to a 8-bit signed integer array.

```
Function GetByteArray {

    [cmdletbinding()]

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $HexString
    )

    $Bytes = [byte[]]::new($HexString.Length / 2)

    For($i=0; $i -lt $HexString.Length; $i+=2){
        $Bytes[$i/2] = [convert]::ToByte($HexString.Substring($i, 2), 16)
    }

    $Bytes  
}
```

After using the function the hex is converted to a byte array such as this:

[image: unsigned byte array]

I need to take the unsigned byte array and convert o to 8bit signed byte array, like the one below:

[image: signed 8-bit integer array (byte array)]

Is this possible? If so how can it be implemented?

I've tried using the BitConverter class but, as far as I saw, it can only convert to int16.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To get a `[byte[]]` array** (`[byte]` == [`System.Byte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Byte), an *unsigned* 8-bit integer type):

```sh
$hexStr = 'A591BF86E5D7D9837EE7ACC569C4B59B' # sample input

[byte[]] -split ($hexStr -replace '..', '0x$& ')
```

- `-replace , '..', '0x& '` inserts `0x` before each pair (`..`) of hex digits and inserts a space afterwards, yielding string `'0xA5 0x91 ... '`
- `-split` applied to the resulting string splits the string by whitespace into an *array* of individual byte representations (`'0xA5', '0x91', ...`)
- casting the result to `[byte[]]` helpfully recognizes this hex format directly.

  - Note: If you forget the cast, you'll get an array of *strings*.
- **To get an `[sbyte[]]` array** (`[sbyte]` == [`System.SByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.SByte), a *signed* 8-bit integer), **cast *directly* to `[sbyte[]]` instead**; do *not* try to *combine* the casts: <del>`[sbyte[]] [byte[]] (...)`</del>)

**Simpler PowerShell (Core) *7.1+* alternative**, using the .NET 5+ [`[System.Convert]::FromHexString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.FromHexString) method:

```sh
$hexStr = 'A591BF86E5D7D9837EE7ACC569C4B59B' # sample input

# Directly returns a [byte[]] array.
# Cast to [sbyte[]] if you need [sbyte] instances.
[System.Convert]::FromHexString($hexStr)
```

---

If you're ***given* a `[byte[]]` array that you *then* want to convert to `[sbyte[]]`**, use the following (there may be more efficient approaches):

```sh
[byte[]] $bytes = 0x41, 0xFF # sample input; decimal: 65, 255

# -> [sbyte] values of:  65, -1
[sbyte[]] $sBytes = $bytes.ForEach('ToString', 'x') -replace '^', '0x'
```

Applied to your sample values, in decimal notation:

```sh
# Input array of [byte]s.
[byte[]] $bytes = 43, 240, 82, 109, 185, 46, 111, 8, 164, 74, 164, 172
# Convert to an [sbyte] array.
[sbyte[]] $sBytes = $bytes.ForEach('ToString', 'x') -replace '^', '0x'
$sBytes # Output (each signed byte prints on its own line, in decimal form).
```

Output:

```
43
-16
82
109
-71
46
111
8
-92
74
-92
-84
```