# Converting a hex string to base 64 in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, base64, hex

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the following Python snippit in PowerShell:

```
allowed_mac_separators = [':', '-', '.']
for sep in allowed_mac_separators:
    if sep in mac_address:
        test = codecs.decode(mac_address.replace(sep, ''), 'hex')
        b64_mac_address = codecs.encode(test, 'base64')
        address = codecs.decode(b64_mac_address, 'utf-8').rstrip()
```

It takes a MAC address, removes the separators, converts it to hex, and then base64. (I did not write the Python function and have no control over it or how it works.)

For example, the MAC address `AA:BB:CC:DD:E2:00` would be converted to `AABBCCDDE200`, then to `b'\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xe2\x00'`, and finally as output `b'qrvM3eIA'`. I tried doing something like:

```
$bytes = 'AABBCCDDE200' | Format-Hex
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($bytes);
```

but that produces `MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".` and I'm not really sure what it's looking for. All the examples I've found utilizing that call only have one argument. This works:

`[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('AABBCCDDE200'))`

but obviously doesn't convert it to hex first and thus yields the incorrect result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about using the `.Bytes` method of `$bytes`?
For example running: `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes.Bytes)`.

Comment: MAC addresses are already in hex. The python script looks like it **decodes** the MAC from hex to UTF8, then encodes the bytes as base64 just like your `[System.Convert]` code in powershell.

Comment: Also, using `$bytes.Bytes` will fix the error you're seeing, but it's equivalent to the `UTF8.GetBytes` method

Comment: Good to know about `.Bytes`, @Cpt.Whale; note that in _Windows PowerShell_ it is the - lossy - `ASCII.GetBytes` method.
While this distinction doesn't matter in the case at hand, note that using `.Bytes`  would _not_ work in this case, because you'd effectively get byte values reflecting the *ASCII code points* of characters such as `A` - whereas what's needed is the interpretation of these characters as _hex digits_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# Remove everything except word characters from the string.
# In effect, this removes any punctuation ('-', ':', '.')
$sanitizedHexStr = 'AA:BB:CC:DD:E2:00' -replace '\W'

# Convert all hex-digit pairs in the string to an array of bytes.
$bytes = [byte[]] -split ($sanitizedHexStr -replace '..', '0x$& ')

# Get the Base64 encoding of the byte array.
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

For an explanation of the technique used to create the `$bytes` array, as well as a simpler *PowerShell (Core) 7.1+* / .NET 5+ alternative (in short: `[System.Convert]::FromHexString('AABBCCDDE200')`), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065438/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

[`Format-Hex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex) does not *return* an array of bytes (directly), its primary purpose is to *visualize* the input data in hex format *for the human observer*.

In general, `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.

That said, **in the particular case of `Format-Hex` the output objects**, which are of type [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ByteCollection]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ByteCollection), ***do* contain useful data**, and do contain the bytes of the *transcoded characters* of input strings `.Bytes` property, as [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale) points out.

However, `$bytes = ($sanitizedHexStr | Format-Hex).Bytes` would *not* work in your case, because you'd effectively get byte values reflecting the *ASCII code points* of characters such as `A` (see below) - whereas what you need is the interpretation of these characters as *hex digits*.

But even in general **I suggest *not* relying on `Format-Hex` for to-byte-array conversions**:

- On a philosophical note, as stated, the purpose of `Format-*` cmdlets is to produce *for-display* output, not *data*, and it's worth observing this distinction, this exception notwithstanding - the type of the output object could be considered an *implementation detail*.
- `Format-Hex` converts strings to bytes based on first applying a *fixed character transcoding* (e.g., you couldn't get the byte representation of a .NET string *as-is*, based on UTF-16 code units), and that fixed transcoding *differs* between *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core)*:

  - In Windows PowerShell, the .NET string is transcoded to ASCII(!), resulting in the loss of non-ASCII-range characters - they are transcoded to literal `?`
  - In PowerShell (Core), that problem is avoided by transcoding to UTF-8.

---

The [`System.BitConverter.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToString) failed, because `$bytes` in your code wasn't itself a byte array (`[byte[]]`), only its `.Bytes` property value was (but didn't contain the values of interest).

That said, you're not looking to reconvert bytes to a *string*, you're looking to convert the bytes directly to Base64-encoding, as shown above.

Comment: good to know. I definitely felt like it should be standard, so I'm glad they updated the API to support it. PS Core is easily the future. Thanks again for the answer.