# Why is the decoded byte array different than the original?

Tags: .net, powershell, encryption

When I generate a random byte sequence, decode the sequence into a string representation, then encode it back to a byte array, it is different from the original encoded sequence. See example below:

```
[byte[]]$key = [byte[]]::new(32)
[System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create().GetBytes($key)
$key
```

output:
15
173
198
89
162
161
144
104
125
86
154
204
166
238
193
40
51
58
167
0
150
118
37
203
198
161
64
229
101
25
176
201

```
$decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($key)
$encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($decoded)
$encoded
```

output:
15
239
191
189
239
191
189
89
239
191
189
239
191
189
239
191
189
104
125
86
239
191
189
204
166
239
191
189
239
191
189
40
51
58
239
191
189
0
239
191
189
118
37
239
191
189
198
161
64
239
191
189
101
25
239
191
189
239
191
189

The byte sequence was clearly modified after decoding/encoding. This process works fine if I use `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode...`. It seems that UTF8 can't handle certain bytes, but I was under the impression that UTF8 should be able to handle any character in the unicode standard. Can someone explain why this happens? Please and thanks

Comment: You're starting out with random bytes, then trying to UTF8-*decode* them into a string. That doesn't make any sense since they are not the valid UTF-8 encoding of a valid string. There are many sequences of bytes that are impossible to achieve using UTF-8 encoding of a string, therefore they cannot be decoded into a string. I don't know what .net does in such a case but in other languages the decoder will simply replace undecodable byte sequences with a default character, thereby corrupting the data.

Comment: UTF8 can handle any character in the Unicode Standard. But neither Unicode nor UTF8 are random; they both have rules. Random bytes probably won't follow the rules and are neither Unicode nor UTF8. Think of other data formats, like JPEG or PDF. Those are made of bytes, right? But not random bytes; a bunch of random bytes probably won't be JPEG or PDF either.

Comment: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html - encoding backwards

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this? Is it just for academical purposes or is there a real, practical use case?

Comment: @zett42 Purely academic. Just something I came across when messing around with the .net prng for generating aes keys. Never needed to put much thought into character encodings before, so I'm just curious.

Comment: The frequently repeated sequence 239 191 189 or hex encoded 0xEFBFBD in the corrupted data is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode replacement character [U+FFFD](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFFD) used when decoding failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not nearly an expert on encodings but here are few notes:

1. From [`Encoding.UTF8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-7.0) docs:

   > This property returns a UTF8Encoding object that encodes Unicode (UTF-16-encoded) characters into a sequence of one to four bytes per character, and that decodes a UTF-8-encoded byte array to Unicode (UTF-16-encoded) characters.
2. Not every possible single byte represents a single valid character in UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 is a variable-width character encoding standard that uses between one and four eight-bit bytes to represent all valid Unicode code points. If you check wiki article for [encoding explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) you will see that single byte handles only 128 code points (0-127), so following will already "break" the encode-decode:

   ```cs
   var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 128 });
   var bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s); // [239, 191, 189]
   ```
3. Personally I would try using `Convert.ToBase64String()`/`Convert.FromBase64String()` (or `Convert.ToHexString()`/`Convert.FromHexString()` if available) pair to encode-decode.

Answer (score 0):

[Guru Stron's helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956413/45375) explains why there is no good reason to bring *text* encodings into the mix, given that you're dealing with random, arbitrary *bytes*.

Your best bet for **converting byte arrays (`[byte[]`) to and from *strings*** is to use a **separator-less list of two-digit *hex* representations**, using [`[System.BitConverter]::ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.BitConverter.ToString) in *Windows PowerShell*, or, more easily, in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)  v7.1+, [`[System.Convert]::ToHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToHexString) and [`[System.Convert]::FromHexString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.FromHexString):

```bash
# Simple sample input byte array.
[byte[]] $bytes = 9, 65, 66 # same as: 0x9, 0x41, 0x42

# PowerShell (Core) 7.1+ / .NET 5+ solution:
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7) {

  # Convert the byte array to a "byte string"
  # -> '094142'
  $byteString = [Convert]::ToHexString($bytes)

  # Convert the "byte string" back to a [byte[]] array.
  $bytesAgain = [Convert]::FromHexString($byteString)

}
# Windows PowerShell solution:
else {

  # Convert the byte array to a "byte string".
  # [BitConverter]::ToString() uses '-' as a separator, which
  # -replace '-' removes.
  # -> '094142'
  $byteString = [BitConverter]::ToString($bytes) -replace '-'

  # Convert the "byte string" back to a [byte[]] array: manual parsing required.
  [byte[]] $bytesAgain = -split ($byteString -replace '..', '0x$& ')  
}

# Show results:
[pscustomobject] @{
  InputBytes = $bytes
  ByteString = $byteString
  ReconvertedBytes = $bytesAgain
}
```

Output:

```bash
InputBytes  ByteString ReconvertedBytes
----------  ---------- ----------------
{9, 65, 66} 094142     {9, 65, 66}
```

- For an explanation of the `-split ($byteString -replace '..', '0x$& ')` operation used above, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065438/45375).